# How should I configure `Concurrent batches per shard` when using lambda to read stream from Dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Dynamodb table enabled stream to a lambda function. I have configured `Concurrent batches per shard` to be 1 which I expect the maximum concurrency of my lambda is only 1. But when monitoring the lambda metrics, I see there are multiple lambda instance running at the same time.

My question is that how `Concurrent batches per shard` relate to a lambda concurrency?

Does one shard include all records relate to the same partition key?

My other configuration looks like:

[image]

If one shard includes update records from the same partition key, then if I configure more than 1 concurrencies per shard, does it mean multiple lambda invocations includes records from the same partition key? If yes, how does it handle processing records in order?

For example, I have 10 updates on the same record in a Dynamodb table at the same time. If there are more than 1 concurrencies per shard, will the 10 updates come to different lambda invocation via stream?

Does the shard also have anything to do with sort key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple invocations as you have multiple shards in the stream. Stream shards are tightly bound to DynamoDB partitions and therefore also bound to Lambda invocations.

`DynamoDB Partitions : Stream shards : Lambda invocations`

`1 : 1 : 1`

Therefore even with a concurrency of 1 per shard, you will still have `n` invocations or the lambda, where `n = no of partitions/shards`.

Comment: Do you mean 1 shard maps to 1 partition keys? If I have more than 1 concurrency per shard, does it mean I will receive records stream in different lambda invocations which are from the same partition key? Will it cause out of order issue?

Comment: I put an example in the question about what I mean.

Comment: No… 1 shard maps to 1 physical partition, which could contain millions of items. There is not order guarantee on just a partition key, but there is item level ordering that will be maintained while using parallelization.

Comment: what is the different between physical partition and partition key?

Comment: A physical partition is responsible for a range of keys. Partition keys are hashed and that hash value is used to determine the partition it lives. So a physical partition could hold potentially millions of unique partition keys.

Comment: So `Concurrent batches per shard` basically only means physical partition? What is the benefits on configuring 1 concurrent batch per shard?

Comment: That's the default number. If your lambda cannot keep up with the rate of events in the stream you can increase it up until 10.